# Этимология предлогов

Tags: этимология

Слова предлоги: «над», «под», «перед», «за(д)» наводят на предположение, что в составе этих слов и в их эпицентре, существует нечто (некто) «Д».
Если «Д» действительно существует, - то кем (чем) может быть, как могут называться его правая и левая стороны?
Может ли, это (этот) «Д» проявлять себя в словах «ряд (ом)», «среди (посередине)»?

Comment: Переформулируйте, если действительно есть проблема. Сожмите до одного вопроса, для начала.

Comment: сам думал такой вопрос задать. Вообще об этимологии предлогов

Answer (score 1):

Буква "д" в перечисленных предлогах - этимологически суффикс.

"Ряд(ом)" и "среди" (и производные) предлогами не являются.

> ПЕРЕД. Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -дъ, ср. под, зад) от предлога
>   *perъ, ныне известного у нас лишь как приставки пере- и пре (из ст.-сл.). См. первый. Перед буквально — "то, что впереди".

Приведу ещё пример из Шанского - с не сразу понятым "зад":

> ЗАД. Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -д-) от предлога за. Ср. с тем
>   же суффиксом под, над, перед.
>
> ЗА. Общеслав. Первичное значение — пространственное ("позади"), другие
>   (временно́е, причинное) являются вторичными.

На примере наречия "позади" мы можем наблюдать "переднюю" и "заднюю" часть слова, где "водоразделом" является исторический суффикс **-д-**.

> ПОЗАДИ. Искон. Сращение предлога **по** и формы род. п. сущ. **зад**.

Говоря о наречиях, мы обнаруживаем

> префиксально-суффиксальные наречия, единичные по составу аффиксов:
>   впереди (в-...-и), позади (по-...-и), издали (из-...-и), отчасти
>   (от-... -и), наутро (на-...-о), замужем (за-...-|о|м), сыздетства
>   (сыз-...-a, прост.), в охотку (в-... -ку, прост.).

То есть у наречий нет и не может быть окончаний, это неизменяемая часть речи;

есть приставка - корень - суффикс.

Существительное "ряд" всё является корнем-основой, упомянутый суффикс -д- ни при чём.

> РЯД. Общеслав. Того же корня, что орудие, лит. rinda "ряд, линия",
>   латышск. rist, riedu "приводить в порядок".

[**Словарь Н. Шанского**](http://www.slovorod.ru/etym-shansky/index.html) (кликать по буквам алфавита).

[**Словообразование наречий**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/976-1031.html).

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что в данном случае это "Д" происходит от славянской буквы "Т" ("Твердо"), которая могла обозначать понятие "Тело". Насчет "рядом", "среди" - думаю, что это "Д" в этих словах себя не проявляет.

Comment: Очень холодно. Очень.

Answer (score 0):

У П.Я.Черныха еще говорится, что предлоги появлялись из неслужебных частей речи, это нередкое явление в истории языков вообще. Например, "под" - это "низ", "дно" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Лингвист, академик Андрей Зализняк, утверждает, что в предлогах *по-д, на-д, пере-д, за-д* суффикс -д происходит от глагола "деть". *На-д* — "находится на".

Источник: https://youtu.be/oLGcD1ACbZo?t=20m